# Windows explorer(explorer.exe in task manager) iis not working?

Tags: windows

I downloaded a theme and installed it
now when I open windows 8 a black screen appears and only ctrl+alt+delete is working
now I need to go to control pannel and uninstall the theme.
and the hotkey of control pannel is also not working
Thanx in advance

Comment: This is not a programming question... It is off topic on SO. Might want to take a look at Super User (another StackExchange website)

Answer (score 0):

Once you login to windows 8, then press 'Windows key + R', It will open run window and there type 'control' without quotes.
It will open control panel and from there you can uninstall this theme. I guess after you uninstall everything will be Ok as before.